# SSRS - Category Groups Expression - Group By Field Null or Not Null

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I  have a dataset that has 2 fields. Like below:

Change Number | Project Reference

1251554456465  |   5336

2546546546546 |

3216546546466 | 5534

Some values in Project Reference will have null entries.

I want to show a Pie chart that shows 2 categories based on this data:
Category 1 - Changes that have a Project Reference 
Category 2 - Change that have NO Project Reference  (ie project reference is null)

I have tried to do an expression in the Category Groups section like below:

```
=(Fields!projectRef.Value is nothing)
```

This shows

[image]

I think I am halfway there I just need help to finish it off and include the category where the expression results to false as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track.

For the Category Group expression, use something like:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!projectRef.Value), "Has Project", "No Project")
```

i.e. use an `IIf` expression to assign one of two values based on the result of the `IsNothing` expression, which checks for NULLs.

With your data:

[image]

I have a simple Chart:

[image]

The value is just a count of items in the category.

I've set **Label** and **Group** on to the expression above under the Category Group properties:

[image]

Result looks good:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I think its something like system.dbnull.value or system.dbnull that you need to compare to

eg:

```
=(Fields!projectRef.Value = System.DbNull.Value)
```

or

```
=(Fields!projectRef.Value = System.DbNull)
```